# Monitoring performance counters

Tags: asp.net, monitoring

I have a smallish ASP.NET site. I want to instrument it, in particular logging the values of performance counters. Is there an external service which would do this? E.g. New Relic RPM, except I need the solution to work on a shared hosting provider where I don't have access to the hosting server.

Thanks